# c++ : warning comparing iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the following function to merge output for 2 containers :

```
template <typename IteratorType1, typename IteratorType2>

void Merge(IteratorType1 src1_begin, IteratorType1 src1_end,
           IteratorType2 src2_begin, IteratorType2 src2_end,
           ostream& out) {
    size_t i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    size_t src1_size = std::distance(src1_begin, src1_end);
    size_t src2_size = std::distance(src2_begin, src2_end);

    while (i1 < src1_size && i2 < src2_size) {
        if (*src1_begin <= *src2_begin) {
            out << *src1_begin << std::endl;
            src1_begin++;
            i1++;
        } else {
            out << *src2_begin << std::endl;
            src2_begin++;
            i2++;
        }
    }
    while (i1 < src1_size) {
        out << *src1_begin << std::endl;
        src1_begin++;
        i1++;
    }
    while (i2 < src2_size) {
        out << *src2_begin << std::endl;
        src2_begin++;
        i2++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get a warning message at line ("comparison of integers of different signs") :

```
if (*src1_begin <= *src2_begin) {
```

Here is a use case :

```
template <typename T, typename S>
void MergeSomething(const list<T>& src1, const vector<S>& src2, ostream& out) {
    Merge(src1.cbegin(), src1.cend(), src2.cbegin(), src2.cend(), out);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v2{65, 75, 85, 95};
    set<unsigned> my_set{20u, 77u, 81u};

    cout << "Merging set and vector:"sv << endl;
    MergeSomething(my_set, v2, cout);
}
```

Is there any solution for it?

How can I silence the warning, given that I am certain that the comparison is actually ok?

Comment: what do you call this function with?

Comment: put a use-case in my question

Comment: Well, this warning is due to your types, nothing to do with your use of templates.

Probably you can force cast, but this warning is meaningful warning.

Comment: What result do you expect of `UINT_MAX - 10 <= -1`, e.g. `vector<int> v2{-1};` and `set<unsigned> my_set{UINT_MAX - 10};`?

Comment: Side remark: better to use and check the iterator directly in the while loop since std::distance may take O(n) for any iterator (e.g. std::set; std::list) except a random access iterator (e.g. std::vector).

Comment: [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CJRmSVRXVmLO48Ib) you can see the reason for this warning. In this example `4294967285u <= -1` is true. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: @jabaa there is a guarantee in my code that ranges for containers are equal( I mean for example it is 0..100 only), only type mismatch - so it is not possible to compile with -Wfatal-errors

Comment: Why do you use `int` if the range is `0..100`? Use `unsigned int` or `int` for both containers and the problem is solved.

Comment: @jabaa 0..100 is just an example to show that ranges for types are equal, of course types differ depending on container and actual range

Comment: Yes, my point is: If you know that both containers have the same range you can use the same types. You can cast one value to the type of the other container. The compiler doesn't know it but you know it. Tell it to the compiler.

Comment: @jabaa yes, you are right - but I don't want to waste time casting - I need to put values to the stream in the right order, so casting containers could be time expensive

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you can (and should) get rid of `i1`, `i2`, `src1_size`, and `src2_size` and instead compare the iterators directly: `while (src1_begin < src1_end && src2_begin < src2_end) ...` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that both containers contain values in the same range you can cast the values to the same type. Following code removes the warning:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std::literals;

template <typename IteratorType1, typename IteratorType2>
void Merge(IteratorType1 src1_begin, IteratorType1 src1_end,
           IteratorType2 src2_begin, IteratorType2 src2_end,
           std::ostream& out) {
    auto src1_size = std::distance(src1_begin, src1_end);
    auto src2_size = std::distance(src2_begin, src2_end);
    decltype(src1_size) i1 = 0, i2 = 0;

    while (i1 < src1_size && i2 < src2_size) {
        if (static_cast<decltype(*src2_begin)>(*src1_begin) <= *src2_begin) {
            out << *src1_begin << std::endl;
            src1_begin++;
            i1++;
        } else {
            out << *src2_begin << std::endl;
            src2_begin++;
            i2++;
        }
    }
    while (i1 < src1_size) {
        out << *src1_begin << std::endl;
        src1_begin++;
        i1++;
    }
    while (i2 < src2_size) {
        out << *src2_begin << std::endl;
        src2_begin++;
        i2++;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename S>
void MergeSomething(const std::list<T>& src1, const std::vector<S>& src2, std::ostream& out) {
    Merge(src1.cbegin(), src1.cend(), src2.cbegin(), src2.cend(), out);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v2{65, 75, 85, 95};
    std::list<unsigned> my_set{20u, 77u, 81u};

    std::cout << "Merging set and vector:"sv << std::endl;
    MergeSomething(my_set, v2, std::cout);
}
```

On [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rrsKW3oY7) you can see that the compiler produces almost the same output.

Comment: Note that using `size_t` for iterator differences will also generate similar warnings. `typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType1>::difference_type i1 = 0, src1_size = std::distance(src1_begin, src1_end);` (and similarly for `i2` and `src2_size`) will fix those.

Comment: Yeah - `auto` is very helpful here! :-)

Comment: i'd rather try to cast to a bigger type, because this will fail when `*src2_begin` is `unsigned` but `*src2_begin` is negative. You silenced the warning, but the issue is still there. "If ... in the same range" its fine, but imho the warning was just good to warning about that.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I mentioned it in the comments. OP is sure that both containers contain variables in the same range. It's not possible that one container contains negative values and the other contains values of type `unsigned`.

Comment: yes, i got it that this is a precondition, but it is not explicit. Possible it is, its just not the way it is supposed to be used.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I understood the question as "How to silence this specific warning because the developer exactly knows that it's correct". Of course, in general you're right as I commented with examples.

Comment: its fine. We dont have an argument. Your answer correctly shows how to silence the warning given that the ranges of values match. I just made a fussy comment questioniong whether this is the best option in general. I admit poor wording of my initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another ( I think more elegant solution ) I just came to

```
template <typename IteratorType1, typename IteratorType2>
void Merge(IteratorType1 src1_begin, IteratorType1 src1_end,
           IteratorType2 src2_begin, IteratorType2 src2_end,
           ostream& out) {
    size_t i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    size_t src1_size = std::distance(src1_begin, src1_end);
    size_t src2_size = std::distance(src2_begin, src2_end);

    while (i1 < src1_size && i2 < src2_size) {
        if (std::less<>()(*src1_begin, *src2_begin)) {
            out << *src1_begin << std::endl;
            src1_begin++;
            i1++;
        } else {
            out << *src2_begin << std::endl;
            src2_begin++;
            i2++;
        }
    }
    while (i1 < src1_size) {
        out << *src1_begin << std::endl;
        src1_begin++;
        i1++;
    }
    while (i2 < src2_size) {
        out << *src2_begin << std::endl;
        src2_begin++;
        i2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, there is less_equal also available - and from my function perspective there is no difference